# Installation of Flamenco Worker

Tags: rendering, add-on

I want to run Flamenco on the Blender Cloud server.

The installation of Flamenco Manager is OK (just be careful to run all the programs while being administrator). I downloaded the cloud add-on for Blender and now I can upload files in my Manager from Blender.

When I look at my Manager, my job is queued forever. I think it's normal because Flamenco Worker has not been installed yet.

The problem is precisely with Flamenco Worker:

1. **I don't know if the folder where I extract the ZIP file is important** (I unzip it in the folder "Blender Foundation").
2. **When I run "flamenco-worker.exe" (in administrator mode), this appears in the black box and then the black box closes:**

```
2020-05-29 11:47:15,572     INFO flamenco_worker.cli Starting Flamenco Worker 2.4

2020-05-29 11:47:15,572     INFO flamenco_worker.ssdp_discover Finding Flamenco Manager through UPnP/SSDP discovery.
```

3. **I have not really good knowledge in programming and in data management. And I don't understand very well the "READ-Me" inside the Flamenco Worker**:

> - Install [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and make sure the `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` binaries are   on `$PATH`. If you only intend to run
>     Flamenco Worker and not run any unit tests, you can   skip `ffprobe`.
>
>   - Install Flamenco Worker in one of two ways:
>   - If you have a distributable zip file (see
>       Packaging for distribution) unzip it, `cd` into it,
>       then run `./flamenco-worker` (or `flamenco-worker.exe` on Windows).
>   - If you have a copy of the source files, run `pipenv install` then run `flamenco-worker`.
>       This requires Python 3.7 or newer.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The question is about Flamenco v2. By now version 3 is released, which is considerably simpler to install & use. Check https://flamenco.blender.org for downloads & documentation.